# transitive or intransitive verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammar-myths

A simple way to check whether a verb is transitive or intransitive is to ask the question what or whom after the verb. If you can answer what or whom then the verb is transitive otherwise it is not.

I have confusion in these two examples

1. *Separate townships have coalesced into a single,sprawling colony.*
2. *The atoms were coalesced into a larger molecule.*
3. *The rebel units coalesced into one army to fight the invaders.*

I am sure that in example 3 coalesced is  an intransitive verb and in example 2 it is transitive. My question is that when I can answer *what* after all three examples. Then how come they are different? 
In example 1 we can say separate townships coalesced into what?
In example 2 we can say the atoms coalesced into what?
In example 3 it can be questioned that rebel units coalesced into what?

My questions are :
Is the example 1 transitive or intransitive?
Is answering what or whom after an verb a reliable method to identify its transitive or intransitive property?
Is there any other method or a reliable online source which can identify these?

Comment: "Into ..." is a preposition phrase, so it can't be a direct object, meaning that "coalesce" is intransitive in your examples.

Comment: @BillJ....But I have taken these examples from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coalesced  this link. Its clearly mentioned example 2 is transitive and 3 is intransitive.

Comment: It's wrong. How can a verb possibly be transitive if it doesn't have a direct object? It would be transitive in the active voice "X coalesced the atoms into a larger molecule", but when that clause is converted into the passive voice the clause (and its verb) become intransitive.

Comment: @BillJ...I am also in doubt as it is a very reputed website. So I was thinking may be there is some other grammatical rule which I don't know. Do you know any method or trick to identify the verbs usage as transitive or intransitive?

Comment: It's simple. A verb is only transitive if it actually has a direct object. And note that objects are **always** noun phrases, never preposition phrases or any other kind of phrase (or clause). In all your examples, the verb "coalesce" has an _into_  ... preposition phrase as complement, and hence must be intransitive.

Comment: @BillJ...but a preposition phrase can also be a part of a noun phrase. Check this wiki link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase .  For instance, She was sitting in the drawing room of her aunt.

Comment: Yes, PP's can occur in NPs as in your example, but that doesn't  mean that the NP "the drawing room of her house" is the direct object. That would be an impossible anlysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108599/discussion-between-sudhir-sharma-and-billj).

Comment: Why? I've explained this to you several times. You can believe whatever you want.